# Eclipse claims I have a missing </application> tag; can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Getting this error:

```
Parser exception for C:\Users\Richy\workspace\Networking\AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>".    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.Networking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.Networking.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

It's getting me mad because I cannot figure it out. I've read other questions on here regarding the same error but I don't see that I've made the same mistake as them.

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean

Comment: @RaghavSood that gave me a shorter but similar error message. And now in my Main Activity it says that 'R' can't be resolved to a variable.

Comment: You have a problem in one of your xml files which prevents the R class from being generated.

Comment: @Luksprog the only two that I've touched are the main layout and the Manifest file.

Comment: Though I'm curious, do I even need the main layout XML if I'm making the layout through the class file itself?

Comment: In eclipse there is a `Problems` view. Can you check and see what you have there?

Comment: Why did somebody just randomly downvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding the project from scratch via the "Project" tab.
Typically "Build Automatically" is checked, but try "Clean..." and then "OK".

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact problem when placing a `<uses-permission>` tag below the `<application>` tag. Lint is *supposed* to throw a warning:

```
<uses-permission> tag appears after <application> tag
```

But in my case it didn't, and simply refused to generate R.java. Try moving it to just after the `<uses-sdk>` tag and recleaning your project.